# Ionic and CakePHP login

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cakephp-2.0, ionic-framework

I am trying to post login credentials to `CakePHP API` using `$http.post()` in my ionic app running at  `localhost:8100`. I am getting

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/app/users/login.
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

then I tried using `$http.jsonp()` and I am able to send my login credentials via url like

```
$http.get(
'http://localhost/app/users/login.json?
callback=JSON_CALLBACK
&username='+data.username+'
&password='+data.password
);
```

Now I am able to login in Cake Controller using

```
if ($this->request->is('get')) {
    $this->request->data['User']['username']=$_GET['username'];
    $this->request->data['User']['password']=$_GET['password'];

    if ($this->Auth->login()) {  
        $user['name']=$_SESSION['Auth']['User']['name'];
        $user['id']=$_SESSION['Auth']['User']['id'];
    } else {
        $user['name']='Fake';
        $user['id']='Fake';
    }
    $user = json_encode($user);  
    $user=$this->finish($user);
    $this->set(array('user'=>$user,'_serialize'=>array('user')));
}
```

everything works fine for me,
but my question is "**Is it a best practice to implement login????**".
Please suggest me.
Thanks

Comment: lot of learning happened, now cors errors gone by setting up headers in cakephp controllers and found some best references for the  Login Authentication in AngularJS. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try using

```
$this->response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

in controller to enable CORS in cakephp and use POST method to login not the JSONP.